# Conflict on ORACLE_HOME: OC4J + Oracle Database 10g (10.2.0) on Windows XP

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

My project requires me to use OC4J and Oracle Database system. Therefore, I go to Oracle web page to download OC4J Application Server (oc4j_extended_101350) and Oracle Database 10g.

Installation of OC4J is simple. I just unzip it to a folder and set the JAVA_HOME and ORACLE_HOME. Then everything is fine.

But then, Oracle Database cannot be installed successfully and it stops at installation of Network Configuration Assistant.

Finally, I found out that OC4J Application Server and Oracle Database 10g need different ORACLE_HOME.

Anyone can suggest what is going on ? How can I put two things on Windows XP ?

Answer (score 0):

The ORACLE_HOME variable is the software installation directory for EACH INDEPENDANT PRODUCT, so when you say, for example, that the OC4J Oracle Home is C:\oracle\oc4j10135, then you would install the Oracle Database at something like C:\oracle\ora10gdb. When starting and stopping the oc4j instance, I would recommend a batch script that sets the oracle_home environment variable manually so that you are explicit in your execution environment.

Specifically, in order to install both in your environment, UNSET the ORACLE_HOME environment variable that you or the software configured with the OC4J installation and make sure to install the Oracle Database software to an empty directory.